make power series expansion and discard higher order terms
I would like to simplify equation by using Taylor-expansion and limit approximation
Background:
Limit approximation is as follows
$$\ln \left (\prod(1+\frac{1}{2^n}) \right) = 
\sum \ln \left (1+\frac{1}{2^n} \right ) \approx
\sum \frac{1}{2^n} =
2$$
Stirling's Approximation  is as follows
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n$$
where
$$(2n)! \sim \sqrt{2\pi 2n}\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n} = \sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n} = 2\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac {2n} e\right)^{2n}$$
Problem:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!\sqrt{n}}{n!^24^n}$$
It can be inferred from  Stirling's Approximation that
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\approx\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}}{2\pi n\left(\frac{n}e\right)^{2n}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;. $$
Furthermore,
$$n!^2 \sim \left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\left(\frac n e\right)^n\right)^2
=2\pi n \cdot \left(\frac n e\right)^{2n}$$
$$4^n= (2^2)^n = 2^{2n}$$
where$$2^{2n}\cdot
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\pi 4^n}
= 
2^{2n}\cdot
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\pi 2^{2n}}
= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}2^{2n}}{\pi 2^{2n}}
= \frac {\sqrt \pi}{\pi}
= \pi^{1/2} \cdot \pi^{-1} = \pi^{-1/2} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{\pi}}$$
My efforts
Using the power expansion,
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
I obtain
$$f(x) = \frac{\log{(x+1)}}{\sin(x)}=\frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right) } { x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^6\right)}$$

Treat $x$ as a constant. Start with the approximation
$\frac{ 1}{ 1+ \rho+ x(\sigma-\rho)} = [1- \rho -x(\sigma-\rho)] +o(\epsilon)$;
then multiply by the numerator  $\sigma-\rho$ and use the given information about the behavior of the individual products that arise.
